# Can we change bundle display name of the iphone project at the end?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, xcode4, ios4

Is it possible to change the name of the project? if possible, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by change the name of project ? If you want to change the name that display below the icon in iPhone how screen then you can change the `bundle display name` in your project `info.plist`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xcode 3.2.5 Use Project->Rename option to rename project. If you are using Xcode 4.2 Just simply click on project name till it appears that you can edit projectname.

Answer (score 0):

Bundle display name In the main plist for the app itself.  For the project, fn+click on the title (maybe twice) in the finder or in Xcode (it's safer in the finder) and it will be editable.